# Acessing ArrayAdapter in onCreate from another class

Tags: android, adapter, android-context

```
public class controller extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Context currentContext = this;
    final BlinkAPI blinkAPI = new BlinkAPI(currentContext);


    lvRadio = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewRadio);
    }
    ...
   }
   //***********************************
   //Separate file

   public class BlinkAPI {

private static Context mContext;
static ListView radioLV;


public BlinkAPI( Context ctx)
{
    BlinkAPI.mContext = ctx;

    radioLV = (ListView )((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.ListViewRadio); 

}

private static void updateRadioTitles( )    {
        radioTitleAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) radioLV.getAdapter();
        ...//Get titleStr etc
        radioTitleAdapter.add(titleStr);        
        radioTitleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

This code crashes out

Answer (score 1):

First of all: raukodraug and Flavio are right! You cann call:

```
myAdapter = radioLV.getAdapter();
```

to get the adapter of the ListView.

However you said, that you like to update the Adapter. If you wanna do that, your activity needs to hold that adapter as a variable, like so:

```
private Adapter myAdapter;
```

If you now want to update the adapter you can call the following method (make sure that you make these calls on the UI-Thread, otherwise the listview wont be updated):

```
myAdapter.add(newItem); // whatever item you might want to add
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: context for myAdapter contructor? this won't work  ArrayAdapter<String> radioTitleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( null, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,radioTitleArrayList);

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `ListView` you can use `radioLV.getAdapter()`

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain adapter by invoking radioLV.getAdapter()

But you cant modify it (add\remove items). To modify it - create and set new adapter, or write an extension of ArrayAdapter and add a method setObjects to it.

Comment: When I try to add the adapter to the ListView lvRadio the prog crashes at that point

Comment: May be you do that not in UI thread? Try radioLV.post(new Runnable (public void run() { radioLV.setAdapter(..); radioTitleAdapter.add(titleStr);}});)